# hi my name is adam leit how can i use this

Tags: c++, file, split, binary

```
void SplitFile(string sourcefile, string destinationfile) {
    ifstream fin(sourcefile, ifstream::binary);
    ofstream fout(destinationfile, ofstream::binary);
    fin.seekg(0, fin.end);
    long size = fin.tellg();
    fin.seekg(0, fin.beg);

    delete[]buf;
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
}
```

how i know this code can build
my idea is read size of source file . then divide byte and write destination But I don't know how to divide .

-requirements of the assignment is user will enter :

MYSPLITFILE -s D:/film.mkv -d D:/par1 -sizeapart 1000000

Names of splitted parts are: film.mkv.part01, film.mkv.part02, film.mkv.part03...

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a file is normally simple.

The requirments for the comand line make life difficult.

And, you can either specify the size of the parts or the number of the parts. Additionally, you need to take into account that the parts may not be equal in size. If your source file size is 20 and you request a part size of 7, then you need to write 3 files. 2 with 7 bytes and 1 with 6 ybtes.

You can use integer division and modula division to get those values

```
20 / 7 = 2
20 % 7 = 6
```

The evaluation of the comand line parameters is the most difficult part. I created a separate function for this.

I use the [C++ std::filesystem libraray](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) to do all the work related to files.

Please see a full example. This is example code.  It could be implemented like this in C++. Bute, of course, there are many other possible solutions. But it shoud give you and idea on how it could work.

You will not understand it. It uses C++ features heaviliy. But, do not give up early. Go through it line by line and google everything. Then you may learn at least the concept and you can implement it with your own words.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <tuple>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr size_t NumberOfArgumentGroups = 3;
constexpr int NumberOfArguments = 7;

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

const std::string parameterExplanation{ "Please invoke program with parameters:\n-s path_of_source_file "
"-d path_of_destination -numpart x\nor\n-s path_of_source_file "
"-d path_of_destination -sizeapart x\n\n" };

std::tuple<bool, fs::path, fs::path, std::uintmax_t, std::uintmax_t> checkProgramArguments(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    bool ok{ true };                // Indicates, if there was an error or not
    fs::path sourceFilePath{};      // Path and file name of source file
    fs::path destinationFilePath{}; // Output directory part
    size_t numberOfParts{};         // So many parts are requested via option
    unsigned long partSize{};       // The outpit file size requested via option

    // First check the overall number of parameters
    if (NumberOfArguments != argc) {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error:" << parameterExplanation;
        ok = false;
    }
    // Now go through all parameters and check them
    else for (size_t group{}; group < NumberOfArgumentGroups; ++group) {

        // Get the option
        std::string option(argv[group * 2U + 1U]);

        // Specification of source path?
        if ("-s" == option) {
            // Get the source path
            sourceFilePath = argv[group * 2U + 2U];
            // And check, if the file exists and if it is a regurlar file
            if (!fs::exists(sourceFilePath) || !fs::is_regular_file(sourceFilePath)) {
                std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Problem with source file:\n" << sourceFilePath.string() << "\n";
                ok = false;
            }
        }
        // Specification of destination directory?
        else if ("-d" == option) {
            destinationFilePath = argv[group * 2U + 2U];
            // Check, if directory exists
            if (!fs::exists(destinationFilePath) || !fs::is_directory(destinationFilePath)) {
                std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Destination file path does not exist\n" << destinationFilePath.string() << "\n";
                ok = false;
            }
        }
        // Specification of number of parts?
        else if ("-numpart" == option) {
            char* end;
            // Convert to number
            numberOfParts = std::strtoul(argv[group * 2U + 2U], &end, 10);
            if (0 == numberOfParts) {
                std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Invalid parameter for number of parts: " << argv[group * 2U + 2U] << "\n";
                ok = false;
            }
        }
        // Specification of size of one part
        else if ("-sizeapart" == option) {
            char* end;
            // Convert to size number
            partSize = std::strtoul(argv[group * 2U + 2U], &end, 10);
            if (0 == partSize) {
                std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Invalid parameter for number of parts: " << argv[group * 2U + 2U] << "\n";
                ok = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            // Wrong option specified. Error message
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Invalid option '" << option << "' specified.\n" << parameterExplanation;
            ok = false;
        }
    }
    // Sanity check,. Test combinations of parameters
    if (sourceFilePath.empty() || destinationFilePath.empty() || ((numberOfParts) > 0 && (partSize > 0))) {
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Invalid option combination\n" << parameterExplanation;
        ok = false;
    }
    return { ok, sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath, numberOfParts, partSize };
}


// Driver code
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Check and evaluate comand line parameter
    if (const auto& [ok, sourceFile, destinationDirectory, numberParts, sizeOfPart] = checkProgramArguments(argc, argv); ok) {

        // Get the size of the source file
        std::uintmax_t fileSize = fs::file_size(sourceFile);

        // Now we need to calculate 3 parameters. 
        std::uintmax_t numberOfParts{};             // Number of files to create
        std::uintmax_t numberOfBytesForLastPart;    // The last file may contain less bytes
        std::uintmax_t partSize{};                  // Size of one output file (except the last

        // So, either the number of parts of the part size is given. Depending on that
        if (numberParts > 0) {

            // Part number was given. Check, if the file size can be devided in exactly number parts
            if (fileSize % (fileSize / numberParts) != 0)

                // No, cannot. We need to write a lst file with less then part size bytes
                // Therefore, decrement the number of output files with full number of bytes
                numberOfParts = numberParts - 1;
            else 
                // We will write numberParts files with equal number of bytes
                numberOfParts = numberParts;

            // Calculate the size of pne output file
            partSize = fileSize / numberOfParts;

            // And the number of vbytes for the last file
            numberOfBytesForLastPart = fileSize % partSize;
        }
        else {
            // The size of a part was given
            partSize = sizeOfPart;
            // Calculate the number of files that we will write
            numberOfParts = fileSize / sizeOfPart;
            // And the size of the last file
            numberOfBytesForLastPart = fileSize % partSize;
        }

        // Open the input file and check, if it could be opened
        if (std::ifstream sourceFileStream(sourceFile, std::ios::binary); sourceFileStream) {

            // Write all parts
            for (std::uintmax_t i{}; i <= numberOfParts; ++i) {

                // Build the file name for the output file
                std::ostringstream outputFileName{};
                outputFileName << sourceFile.filename().string() << ".part" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << i+1;
                // This is a smart overload of the / operator. It will concatenate the path and filename with correct delimiter
                fs::path outputFilePathAndName = destinationDirectory / outputFileName.str();

                // DO only something if we have still bytes to copy
                if (uintmax_t bytesToCopy = ((i == numberOfParts) ? numberOfBytesForLastPart : partSize); bytesToCopy > 0) {

                    // Open the output file for this part and check, if it is open
                    if (std::ofstream outputFileStream(outputFilePathAndName, std::ios::binary); outputFileStream) {

                        // Copy bytes from source to destination
                        std::copy_n(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFileStream),
                            bytesToCopy,
                            std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(outputFileStream));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open destination file: " << outputFilePathAndName << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file: " << sourceFile << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I added many many error checks. You should do this as well.